# How to restrict the call back event fires for the previous video after the video play end reached

Tags: unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

In my unreal engine blueprint, I have the instances of the transition video player which is a type of `media player source` that has been created as a variable.

When the video player reaches the end, I bind it to an event called `OnVideoEnd` from `Bind event to on end reached`.

However, the `OnVideoEnd` has been triggered also for the video that has already been played while the video has ended after playing a new one. How to stop this behavior, and call the OnVideoEnd only when the recent video has been ended. not for the previous one. I want to implement this blueprint only way…

Here the print string is printed in an increment order of the number of videos played, each time a new video is played.

[image]